# My .htaccess file not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have this code on my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?user=$1 [NC, L]
```

This works fine, but since I upgraded my WAMP SERVER, it misbehaves. Actually it redirects to`user.php` but it doesn't pass the query `user=$1`.

So now when I navigate to `user/10/` it directs me to`user.php` but show an error of `undefined index: user`

Secondly, I also have something like this

```
RewriteRule ^accounts/([a-z]+)/?$ account/$1.php [NC, L]
```

This works, but then I noticed something, even if I delete my .htaccess file, the above code still works.

Please I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by `mod_negotiation`. Add this to your htaccess file

```
Options -Multiviews
```